# Combine path from external program with \draw in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, shell-escape

I have an external program bezierplot which returns tikz paths. E. g. `bezierplot 'x^2'` returns `(-2.24,5) parabola bend (0,0) (2.24,5);` with semicolon. Now I want to call the program with shell-escape/write18 inside a LaTeX document (pdflatex) and in text mode this works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\input{|"bezierplot 'x^2' "} % this works: (-2.24,5) parabola bend (0,0) (2.24,5);
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw \input{|"bezierplot 'x^2' "} % this does not work
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work inside the tikzpicture: `! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?`
It seems like the semicolon is not the problem (e.g. I removed it in the program `bezierplot` and used `\draw \input{|"bezierplot 'x^2' "};` instead). When I change the program `bezierplot` such that it returns `\draw (-2.24,5) parabola bend (0,0) (2.24,5);`I then can successfully use `\input{|"bezierplot 'x^2' "}`

What is the point that I have missed? How can I force tikz to concatenate `\draw` with `\input{|"bezierplot 'x^2' "}` and `;` ?

Comment: It is very hard to really answer this question because I cannot try things out since I do not have `bezierplot`. However, I would try `\xdef\myplot{ \input{|"bezierplot 'x^2' "} }` followed by `\draw \myplot ;`.

Comment: @marmot Let's say bezierplot is the following bash program: `echo "(-2.24,5) parabola bend (0,0) (2.24,5)"` Unfortunately, your suggestion as denoted above with \xdef did not work...

Comment: @marmot latex's `\input` isn't expandable

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, thanks, I just figured this out the hard way. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I use `echo` here as an external program returning the path.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\let\zz\@@input
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw \zz|"echo '(-2.24,5) parabola bend (0,0) (2.24,5)'" ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly!  Is there also a way to get the semicolon out of the external program? (So you are only allowed to use `echo '(-2.24,5) parabola bend (0,0) (2.24,5)'`without the semicolon?)

Comment: @LinusRomer sure,  if `echo` (or your program) doesn't add a `;` just end the input with `" ;`

Comment: @LinusRomer I edited the answer (same output)

Comment: Ooops, I could have sworn that this variant did not work some minutes ago, but you are right: It works!