# Input from external program to tikz as a LaTeX command with several arguments

Tags: tikz-pgf, shell-escape

I am in need of a command `\myprogram` that takes 3 optional and 1 mandatory arguments. When using pdfLateX --shell-escape,  `\myprogram`  should call

```
echo '(#1,#2) parabola (#3,#4)'
```

(`echo` stands here as a replacement for an own external program) and should be combined with a `\draw` command from tikz such that

```
\tikz \draw \myprogram[-1][-1][1]{2};
```

gives the same output as

```
\tikz \draw (-1,-1) parabola (1,2);
```

I already have a WORKING solution with only 1 argument (with the help given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419526/combine-path-from-external-program-with-draw-in-tikz)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter\let\zz\@@input\makeatother
\providecommand{\myprogram}[1]{\zz|"echo '(0,0) parabola (1,#1)'" }
\begin{document}
\tikz \draw \myprogram{2};
\end{document}
```

Also, I already have a WORKING solution with multiple arguments for LuaLaTeX (emulating my external program with tex.sprint instead of echo):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\xmyprogram}{O{0} O{0} O{1} m}{\directlua{tex.sprint('(#1,#2) parabola (#3,#4)')}}
\providecommand\myprogram{\romannumeral`\^^@\xmyprogram}
\begin{document}
\tikz \draw \myprogram[-1][-1][1]{2};
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining your two existing pieces gives the working pdfLaTeX shell-escape solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\makeatletter\let\zz\@@input\makeatother
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\xmyprogram}{O{0} O{0} O{1} m}{%
  \zz|"echo '(#1,#2) parabola (#3,#4)'"
}
\providecommand\myprogram{\romannumeral`\^^@\xmyprogram}
\begin{document}
\tikz \draw \myprogram[-1][-1][1]{2};
\end{document}
```

Comment: The small thing that I was missing was putting the `}` on a new line. I never thought that this could make a difference.